# Reusable master/detail view best practice ember

Tags: ember.js

I've been grappling with this relatively simple problem in Ember JS in a variety of my apps. I know this may seem like its been answered seven ways to Sunday but I haven't found a solution that I can actually map to my problem.

Okay, so I need a class master/detail view with a route structure like:

- Admin Dashboard

  - Dashboard
  - Students page (displays a master list of students in a sidebar)
  - Student page (upon selecting a sidebar item, it is selected and "details appears"

This pattern is reused exactly at three different dashboards in my site. The only difference is the record array of students is different for each one. I'm asking what is the most Ember-esque way to accomplish this?

I have tried multiple solutions but each one has its own problems. Using the `{render}` helper to render some universal "students" template breaks because I am leveraging the router and `<li>` tags inside to automatically apply the active class to the selected student, and `students.student` isn't a route in my router. If I add that route, then it routes away from the dashboard parent route (with the navbar, etc).

I basically want to package this view into a component almost and pass it the array to display, but then how do I add the "active" class? Surely there is an easier way then manually adding and removing the class.

Thoughts?

I apologize if my question isn't super clear! Its a subtle distinction.

Comment: Components are probably the best solution, but I don’t understand what problem you’re experiencing with the `active` class. The `link-to` helper adds that class automatically, is that not working for you?

Comment: You could use `Em.CollectionView` for the list of students by passing in a dynamic content option. `{{#view 'students' content=content}}` could then be used in multiple routes and the list of students would be bound to the controller's content.

Comment: @BuckDoyle, its not that the link-to helper isn't working, it is. But I can't link to any specific route in the helper because there is no students/student route in my application. If I add one (via a global resource `students`), then I can't nest the students page under each dashboard. Can you elaborate how components could be used?

Comment: @DuncanWalker, I thought about `Em.CollectionView` but I feel like this wouldn't work. I would have to manually implement adding and removing active classes as the router could no longer handle it (right?). Not that this is difficult, but I'm going for best practice. I feel like there should be a way to encapsulate master/detail view.

Comment: You could have a route but still have nesting, no? If you’re concerned about duplication, you could just have all the nested routes extend a common route.

Comment: Well I don't think I can. For example, if I have an AdminDashboard route with a nested Students route with a further nested Student route, then this will require an adminDashboard/students template, which would be redundant against mentorDashboard/students, and schoolDashboard/students. My goal is to have one `students` template that can link to individual `student` templates, that I can render for each admin/mentor/studentDashboard routes.